# apt-get update fails on HTTP sources (but not HTTPS)

Tags: debian, firewall, apt

I'm getting an error with HTTP sources when trying to run `apt-get update`:

```
root@hostname:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 https://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Err:2 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.184.204 80]
Hit:3 https://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.184.204 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This error doesn't occur when using HTTPS (as shown). There is *also* no issue opening these in a web browser. Unfortunately it looks like the Debian security updates repository ironically doesn't support HTTPS at the moment.

I'm behind a corporate firewall but haven't encountered many issues before, apart from having to add the root cert to new installs. I also haven't encountered any issues with RHEL/CentOS or with Ubuntu. How can I diagnose this? I don't see any logs in the usual locations (`/var/logs/apt`).

Comment: Try going to https://ftp.us.debian.org in a browser behind your company firewall and see what happens.  This happens to me when Comcast is inserting its "You're close to your bandwidth limit" messages into my HTTP (not HTTPS) traffic.

Comment: @LawrenceC Works just fine, both HTTP and HTTPS. I get Oregon State University's mirror.